# Adding Vector Tiles results in 'Network request timed out' in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, vector-tiles, germany

In QGIS 3.28 Firenze on my Windows, I am trying to create a connection to a vector tile server to request contour line tiles.

As the data are open source I can post the server address:

The server has the following link:
[https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/gdz_basemapde_vektor/tiles/v1/bm_web_hl_de_3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf](https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/gdz_basemapde_vektor/tiles/v1/bm_web_hl_de_3857/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pbf)

The style sheet is here:
https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/gdz_basemapde_vektor/styles/bm_web_col.json

What I did so far:

Go to 'Vector Tiles' in the Browser panel, and create a 'New Generic Connection' by setting the parameters as follows:

[image]

When I then click 'ok' and add the new Vector Tile connection as a layer to the project QGIS crashes and the logs say *'Network request https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/gdz_basemapde_vektor/tiles/v1/bm_web_hl_de_3857/.....pbf timed out'*.

Am I doing everything correctly with QGIS? And what do I need to change?
Alternative approaches to try to make it work (e.g. with PyQGIS) are also very welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing I want to clarify is that you are mixing URLs and styles from two different vector tile sets i.e. Basis and Höhenlinien.

Secondly, it looks like the styles for Höhenlinien do not work properly.

I checked the settings provided on the official website of the Bundesamt für Kartographie und Geodäsie: http://gdz.bkg.bund.de/index.php/default/gdz-basemapde-vektor-gdz-basemapde-vektor.html, https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/web_public/gdz/dokumentation/deu/basemap.de_web_vektor.pdf, and the https://basemap.de/web-vektor/.

### Vector Tileset Basis

**URL :**
[https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/gdz_basemapde_vektor/tiles/v1/bm_web_de_3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf](https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/gdz_basemapde_vektor/tiles/v1/bm_web_de_3857/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pbf)

**Style URL :**
https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/gdz_basemapde_vektor/styles/bm_web_col.json

[image: result1]

### Vector Tileset Höhenlinien

**URL :** [https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/gdz_basemapde_vektor/tiles/v1/bm_web_hl_de_3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf](https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/gdz_basemapde_vektor/tiles/v1/bm_web_hl_de_3857/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pbf)

**Style URL :** the https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/gdz_basemapde_vektor/tiles/v1/bm_web_hl_de_3857/bm_web_hl_de_3857.json might be an issue because QGIS gives me: *Error loading style: Could not find layers list in JSON*, however, I can see them in my Browser.

I suggest contacting the Bundesamt für Kartographie und Geodäsie: https://www.bkg.bund.de/DE/Service/Kontakt/kontakt.html

Comment: Thank you, for trying to help!  I just tried it with the the first provided url and style url  for the basic map (so without the contour lines) and everything works just fine. However, it still stays a problem with the contour lines. 
Yes, I will contact the Bundesamt for Kartographie and Geodäsie. Thanks a lot!